# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am tryin to make login in node.js values are already stored in database but it is showing this error when i enter values to login page.

[image]

````
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;
    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                response.redirect('/home');
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }
});

app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        response.send('Welcome back, ' + request.session.username + '!');
    } else {
        response.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    response.end();
});

app.listen(3000,function(request,response){
    console.log("Running");
});```
````

Comment: whats error show?

Comment: Are you sure `results` is type of array? Maybe it's just an object? So maybe check if this is an actualy array with `Array.isArray(results)` ?

Comment: @HalilÇakar results is `undefined`, my guess is its `error`'ing, OP is not looking for it

Comment: I have attached console error picture also

Comment: So it says then maybe check it `if(results && results.length > 0)` ?

Comment: @ Halil Çakar it worked for me :D Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you could try to make this code asynchronous like this because you have an asynchronous operation:

```
app.post('/auth', async function(request, response) {
});
```

After that you can wrap a try-catch block around your code and add an await in front of your query method like so:

```
app.post('/auth', async function(request, response) {
    const username = request.body.username;
    const password = request.body.password;

    if (username && password) {
        try{
        const results = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password]);

        if (results[0] > 0) { //Depending on your library you also have to check if [0] is filled, as the mysql package will give you also the column definitions back in [0][1] 
            request.session.loggedin = true;
            request.session.username = username;
            response.redirect('/home');
        } else {
            response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
        }
        } catch(error){
        // You have to properly send this error to an error-handler
        }
    }
});
```

Also I would work here with proper HTTP-Status codes so your frontend can react better on different status codes.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that in order to use async/await with the mysql package, that you have to install the mysql2 package as this supports promises.